# I'm trying to configure DNS on router but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: networking, dns, internet

Application doesn't let me leave Domain Name blank or anything else. Previous routers I had simple way of adding DNS servers but this new one begs to differ.

[DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuYm4.png)

Comment: Provide more information about the router. Are you sure you can't add anything? The Domain Name should also be an IP from what I understand the back-end. Did you try that?

Open back-end in private window to be sure that there is no caching going on.

Comment: I have not seen this device before, but that does not look like the correct page to fill out information for a DNS client. (Maybe some kind of resolver for authorative domain names). Also, I think you have filled it out wrong - a domain name should not be an IP address.

Comment: thex, davidgo thanks for the replies.

This is a Nokia router for a Fibre connection. You were right DNS configuation  was elsewhere. However, the fields were disabled even though I was logged in as admin. But managed to edit them with browser developer tools, by removing disabled tag on DNS text fields and Save button. :)

Answer (score 1):

GPON Home Gateway. FIbre router made by Nokia.

DNS Configuration is on Network > LAN. If the Primary DNS, Secondary DNS and Save button are disabled, use web browser developer tools and remove "disabled" tags.

[DNS Settings for LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWiem.png)

[OpenDNS test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJRHJ.png)

Comment: Doing like this made router not work at all after restart of applying new empty dns fields with new dns ips.